# How to write a method which will conduct a BLE request and return the corresponding response?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In android  I send the read request to the BLE devices through the following API.

```
boolean success = bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

And got the response on `onCharacteristicRead` callback function.

```
public class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {
    @Override
     public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            //characteristic.getValue() is the reponse.

        } else {


        }
    }
}
```

But I want the reponse as the return of the request function like following :

```
public response_type readStatus(){
     bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
     // Processing
     return  response;
}
```

What is the way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best solution is to use an Interface :

```
public class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback
{
    private GattClientCallBackInterface gattClientCallBackInterface;

    public void setGattClientCallBackInterface(GattClientCallBackInterface gattClientCallBackInterface)
    {
        this.gattClientCallBackInterface = gattClientCallBackInterface;
    }

    public interface GattClientCallBackInterface{
        public void onCharacteristicReadSuccess(byte[] bytes);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            //characteristic.getValue() is the reponse.
            if (gattClientCallBackInterface != null)
            {
                gattClientCallBackInterface.onCharacteristicReadSuccess(characteristic.getValue());
            }
        } else {


        }
    }
}
```

now you just have to implement this GattClientCallBackInterface interface :

```
YourGattClientCallbackObject.setGattClientCallBackInterface(new GattClientCallBackInterface()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCharacteristicReadSuccess(byte[] bytes)
                {

                }
            });
```